# Use iTunes' Up Next function with an API

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, itunes

Is there a way to use iTunes' Up Next function with an API?

I know that you can use Scripting Bridge, but it doesn't cover any of the new functions of iTunes 11.

Comment: => open iTunes with the AppleScript Editor to see the Apple-Script Dictionary that iTunes has.    Anyway I did not found anything for the "Next Up" thingy so I assume it's not in Apple's intention to give access to this or the AppleScript Dictionary isn't up-to-date. Would be cool if they implement it like "next playlist".

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could see a documentation like this. But yes, unfortunately Up Next is not implemented yet...

Comment: BTW: I would also enable "Script Assistant" in the Script-Editor Preferences. Also useful: ctrl-click in a script shows a contextual-menu with handy code-snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iTunes has no public API but the scripting bridge

you could use Applesript UI Scripting I'd wager -- but that would be very fragile

you can also simulate a keypress then:
That less fragile than scripting the visible interface (IMO):
**http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20121203223100335**

TADA -- YAY -- a 'ready' script that will add songs selected to UpNext ::

```
tell application "AppleScript Utility"
    set GUI Scripting enabled to true
end tell

tell application "iTunes"
    --get the song
    set l to playlist "Purchased"
    set t to item 5 of tracks of l

    --focus it in list
    reveal t

    --show window
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    -- option enter
    delay 1
    key down option
    delay 1
    key code 36
    key up option

    -- Click the “Play Song” button in the annoying dialog.
    set w to null
    try
        set w to window "Add to Up Next" of application process "iTunes"
    end try
    if w is not null then
        set b to UI element "Play Song" of w
        click b
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: well UIScripting is basically interfacing with the system by the way of emulating the user. see: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.06/UserInterfaceScripting/index.html

Comment: I was doing a little research, and I'm not sure it that's the right solution. First, the app often has to be frontmost, this would be complete nonsense in my app. Also, the use can see what's actually being clicked. And, the clicks are being stored with x and y axes. That means if they adjust the UI just slightly, it might not work anymore... Am I getting this right?

Comment: yes you are right ... sorry... thats what I meant with 'very fragile'

Comment: @NSAddict Not completely right. The clicks aren't stored as X/Y values but rather as indices of the elements being clicked at, e.g. `button 2 of row 1 of window 1`. Which is still quite fragile, but doesn't mean that if the user resizes the window, your script will break.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks, this already looks a little better, but still you would have to select the right song in the table view...

Comment: @Daij-Djan I guess this is all I can ask for :) Thanks