# How to retrieve the tracks that are in the "Up Next" list on iTunes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, itunes

I'd like to retrieve the name or ID of the tracks that are in the "Up Next" list on iTunes. I've been looking around on the `iTunes.h` file but i can't find anything that performs what I want to do.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659626/use-itunes-up-next-function-with-an-api

Comment: that adds songs to the Up Next list, that's not what i'm looking. oh, and that's not working on my computer, either. i just want to get the list of the tracks

Comment: No, it's about **Up Next** in general. The truth is that there is no way. You simply can't get the songs from Up Next, without a complex and buggy workaround. Look up UI Scripting, if you want to try it. 
Apple doesn't provide anything useful in their API, and if I'm honest, I don't think they ever will.

Comment: thanks man! answer this question with that and i'll accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this related question:
[Use iTunes' Up Next function with an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659626/use-itunes-up-next-function-with-an-api)

The truth is that there is no way.

You simply can't get the songs from Up Next, without a complex and buggy workaround. Look up UI Scripting, if you want to try it. Apple doesn't provide anything useful in their API, and if I'm honest, I don't think they ever will.